# android View animation doesn't working

Tags: android, android-animation

I tried this code and it just doesn't start the animation. the image i putted on the bitmap doesn't move as it should, it's just stay in it's place.
i didn't get any errors and i didn't change the XML file.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.view.View;

public class game  extends View{
    int x = 0;//locations
    int y = 0;
    public game(Context context) {
        super(context); 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Bitmap ball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.t);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Rect rectangle = new Rect();
        rectangle.set(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        Paint red = new Paint();
        red.setColor(Color.RED);
        red.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        canvas.drawRect(rectangle, red);
        if(x < canvas.getHeight())
            x =+ 10;
        else
            x = 0;
        if(y < canvas.getWidth())
            y =+ 10;
        else 
            y = 0;
        Paint a = new Paint();
        canvas.drawBitmap(ball, x, y, a);
        invalidate();//repeat the code 
    }
```

}

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

Try this -

```
 Paint a= new Paint();
 a.setAntiAlias(true);
 a.setFilterBitmap(true);
 a.setDither(true);

 canvas.drawBitmap(ball, x, y, a);
```

Answer (score 0):

call  super.onDraw(canvas) at the and of your function, and don't use invalidate() from OnDraw:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Bitmap ball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.t); 
    Rect rectangle = new Rect();
    rectangle.set(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    Paint red = new Paint();
    red.setColor(Color.RED);
    red.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    canvas.drawRect(rectangle, red);
    if(x < canvas.getHeight())
        x =+ 10;
    else
        x = 0;
    if(y < canvas.getWidth())
        y =+ 10;
    else 
        y = 0;
    Paint a = new Paint();
    canvas.drawBitmap(ball, x, y, a);

    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

you can use this method to invalidate your view every X ms:

```
private void startTimerThread() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                int ms = 500 //example of 0.5 sec   
                Thread.sleep(ms);
            }    
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            handler.post(new Runnable(){
                public void run() {                     
                    invalidate();
                }
            });
        }
    };
    new Thread(runnable).start();
}
```

and call startTimerThread() at your constructor:

```
public game(Context context) {
    super(context); 
    startTimerThread();
}
```